# Mathematical operation expression binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I got this Expression binding:

```
<Text text="{
                                             parts: [
                                             {path: 'amount'}, 
                                             {path: 'currency'}
                                            ],
                                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                            formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}
                                            }"/>
```

now I would like to divide the amount with 100 before I display it in my table, is that possible do that without using an own formatter ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not possible to combine expression binding with types. The types have a formatter built-in already, which means that you would be using two formatters for the same value.

If you want to divide the amount by 100, it would be easiest to just subclass the `Currency` type, and add the division to an override of method `formatValue`.

Comment: so I use like 2 formatters? first one which divides my amount by 100 then one who formats it depending on which currency is used? do you have any short example about this?

Comment: I would recommend subclassing the `sap.ui.model.type.Currency`. You can read how this is done in step 34 of the SAPUI5 walkthrough: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.8/docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html. Once you have subclassed it, override its `formatValue`method and use the subclassed type instead of SAP's standard Currency type. Your own `formatValue` value should be a copy of SAP's, except that it should also divide the value by 100.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by custom formatter function. I am writing it in JavaScript. I hope you can understand.

For more go through: [Custom Formatter Functions](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html)

```
oTxt.bindValue({
                parts: [
                         {path: 'amount'}, 
                         {path: 'currency'}
                  ],

               formatter: function(amount, currency){ 
                   if (amount && currency) {
                         var calculatedAmount = amount/100;
                         return currency+calculatedAmount;
                   } else {
                          return null;
                   }
               }
});
```

Comment: but I would like to still have my formation for the amount depending on which currency it is for example for euros 1.000,00 and for dollars 1,000.00, in your version that would be gone right